# Чем отличается код javascript?

Tags: prototype, javascript

Объясните пожалуйста, кто знает, чем отличается этот код:

```
function Button() {
  this.cc = 0;
  this.clicked = function() {
    this.cc+=1;
    console.log('Clicked ' + this.cc);
  }
}
```

От вот этого:

```
 function Button() {
      this.cc = 0;
    }
    Button.prototype.clicked = function() {
      this.cc+=1;
      console.log('Clicked ' + this.cc);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Внешне - ничем не отличает.
Но внутренне, для случая:

```
function Button() {
  this.cc = 0;
  this.clicked = function() {
    cc+=1;
    console.log('Clicked ' + this.cc);
  }
}
```

`(new Button()).clicked != (new Button()).clicked`

И это реально разные ( почти всегда полностью ) функции, с разным контекстом исполнения, и т.д и т.п...

P.S: В принципи, это можно назвать private свойствами:

```
function Button(){
  var obj_private = {},
      obj_fn = [],
      obj = this;
  for( var fn in this ){
    if ( typeof this[ fn ] === 'function' ){
      obj_fn.push( this[ fn ] );
    }
  }

  this.get_private = function (){
    if (
          ( this == obj ) &&
          ( obj_fn.indexOf( arguments.caller.callee ) != -1 )
        ){
      return private_obj;
    }
  }
}

Button.prototype.clicked = function (){
  var pr = this.get_private();
  pr[ cc ]++;
  console.log( 'Clicked' + pr[ cc ] );
}
```

Comment: Вот это я согласен, если таких кнопок было бы, предположим - 1000 и код был бы написан как в первом случае - было бы создно 1000 по факту одинаковых но "разных" функций, естественно что это излишне :)

Comment: С другой стороны, добавление метода в прототип лишает его частных свойств объекта? это можно как то обойти?

Спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: нет - нельзя... Тм где нужно используются прототипы, а там где они не нужны( "мистер очевидность" ) - не используются ^^

Comment: можно))) покажите что хотите - посмотрим)

Comment: timka_s, самый простой вариант:
function Button() {
  var cc = 0;
  this.clicked = function() {
    cc += 1;
    console.log('Clicked ' + cc);
  }
}

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Первое - создание одного объекта, инициализация у него свойства и добавление к нему одного метода.

Второе - создание одного объекта, инициализация у него свойства и добавление метода к прототипу, то есть ко всем объектам этого типа.

(То есть разница в том, что у *других* объектов этого типа в первом случае нового метода clicked не будет, а во втором - будет.)

Comment: Вариант 

    var a = new Button();
    a.clicked();
    var b = new Button();
    b.clicked();

Работает. Или я что-то сделал неправильно?